# How to increase shadow strength overtime/distance in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow, lighting

I'm trying to increase shadow strength when the object is becoming near to the ground.

Using light source (Directional Light) which is perpendicular on my cube game object (Rotation 90,0,0).

**This is how I want it to appear:**
[image]

*#Workaround which isn't good:*
Manipulating the directional light will work when there is only one falling object, but when there are more than one falling cube it won't work properly at all. As if there are 5 falling objects each one at a different distance from the ground.. no way :/ I don't know how to work this out.

**Any suggestions? I would be so grateful, thanks in advance.**

Comment: would using soft shadows be an option for you? As an alternative (depending on your models of course) you could fake it using a flat 2D version of your object and fade, scale and move it accordingly